# ROS2 Humble on 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: upgrade

im following ROS2 Humble installation in ubuntu 20.04.3

although the documentation says Debian packages are for only 22.04 jammy version,

Co-worker says he installed Debian packages of ROS2 HUmble in ubuntu 20.04 and currently using well

Problem 1: if type sudo apt upgrade (to follow the installation doc), the os version upgrades from 20.04.3LTS to 20.04.6 LTS
Does this mean i have to never use sudo apt upgrade command forever?
or is there a command that doesnt upgrade os version but other packages like python?

Problem 2: if i type sudo-apt-install ros-humble-desktop, i get message
E: Unable to locate package ros-humble-desktop

i searched and there it said i cant install debian package of ros2 humble in ubuntu 20.04.

i tried the lxd container method, and it leads to source installation

Problem 3: What is the 'setup.bash' file path if i installed ros2 humble via lxd container?
i failed to find the installation path of 'setup_bash' file , which is normally located in ./opt/ .

Comment: A release is *year.month* in format, so your release is 20.04 meaning 2020-April release (*2000 is subtracted from year*).  The extra detail only shows your level of upgrades applied; so 20.04.2 highlights a system that should be kept off-line & isn't safe online, having not had any security fixes applied since before [20.04.3](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/08/27/ubuntu-20-04-3-lts-released/) (note: the link I gave is for ISO release, with installed system upgrading **before** that date). A 20.04.3 & 20.04.6 system are both 20.04; only the latter is safe if used online.

Comment: This is a *Question & Answer* site, where your question should **only** contain a single question (*this isn't a forum, https://ubuntuforums.org/ is the address of Ubuntu Forums*).  If you have three questions, you ask three separate questions, with multiple-hidden questions being closed as off-topic as *too broad* (unclear specific question that has a clear answer)

Comment: okay i should use 20.04.6 and consider as 20.04 and should not ask multiple question